# Как вывести все дочерние таксономии родительской таксономии, ноходясь в одной из этих же дочерних?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть родительская таксономия Jane Air. У неё есть три дочерние : Homes, Bicycles, Cars.
Как находясь в одной из этих дочерних таксономий вывести все дочерние таксономии от её родительской, включая её саму ?
То есть, к примеру - я нахожусь в дочерней таксономии Homes, и мне надо вывести все таксономии её уровня по отношению к их родительской таксономии Jane Air.
На выходе мне надо получить просто этот список "Homes, Bicycles, Cars".
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вывод всех "дочек" текущей таксономии, как вывести родителя уже от Вас был вопрос.

get_queried_object()->parent - так получаем ID родительской

```
$term_id = get_queried_object()->parent ;
$taxonomy_name = get_queried_object()->taxonomy;
foreach ( get_term_children( $term_id ,$taxonomy_name  ) as $child  ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
```

get_queried_object() - дает информацию о текущей таксономии (имя, терм, ид и пр)

get_term_children() - дает информацию о "детях"

get_term_link () - формируем линк.

Рекомендую ознакомится с https://wp-kama.ru/function-cat/osnovnoj-zapros довольно не плохая справка

Comment: Мне нужно не текущей..... А у текущей найти родительскую, и вывести конкретно её дочек. Спасибо

Comment: Внес изменения.

Comment: А можно вывести только первый уровень ?
То есть только один уровень вложенности.

Comment: Добавьте проверку в цикле if ($term->parent == $term_id) {выводим дочернюю}

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо большое) буду разбираться в приведенных вами ссылках.

Comment: Ещё один вопрос возник - нужно подставлять другой класс в <li> той таксономии, где я сейчас нахожусь . Как это сделать ?

Comment: if ($term->parent == $term_id):
                                    echo '<li class="menu-item"><a href="' . get_term_link($child, $taxonomy_name) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
                                endif;
Вот то что сейчас есть , а надо если я нахожусь в этой таксономии то  ставить ей другой класс

Comment: не понял вопроса, какой другой класс, отметить ее как-то? если отметить - то добавте условие, типа if (get_queried_object()->term_id==$term->term_id) {один класс} else {второй класс}

Comment: помогло, спасибо большое